# How to view or change OSPF LSA max-age time in Cisco IOS?

Tags: cisco, routing, ospf

Is there any way of viewing or changing OSPF LSA Max-Age time in Cisco IOS?

Answer (score 1):

The **show ip ospf database** command displays the content of the LSDB and verifies information about specific LSAs.

Age column shows the age of the last received LSA, if a newer copy of that LSA gets recieved you would see that the age would be reset to zero and its sequence number would be incremented as well.

MaxAge instead is 1 hour by default and cannot be changed, if any LSA reaches the maximum age it would be flushed, to prevent the valid LSA from reaching its maximum age so being flushed, the originated router would send a new copy of that LSA every 30 minutes with a new sequence number and the age of zero (LSRefreshTime).

MaxAge would be also used on purpose sometimes, for example if the originated router would flush an LSA it would set the LSA age to MaxAge and then resend it to all neighbors, the neighbors would then flush it from the LSDB.

Because this update is only used to refresh the LSDB, it is sometimes called a paranoid update.